# SharePoint Rest call is not returning all fields

Tags: python-3.x, rest, sharepoint

Goal: Have python program pull data from SharePoint so we can store on database.

Issue: I am able to connect to share point and return data, but I am not getting all of the fields I can see when hitting the UI page. The UI page I am hitting is in the list on REST call but is a Custom View

Update: Using the renderashtml I was at least able to see some of the data points I am looking for. I would hope there is a better solution than this

Code:

```
import sharepy
connection = sharepy.connect("https://{site}.sharepoint.com")
r = connection.get("https://{site}.sharepoint.com/{page}/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('{list_name}')/items")
print(r.content)
print(r.json())

#I have also tried 
https://{site}.sharepoint.com/{page}/_api/web/lists('{list_id}')/views('{view_id}')

#I was able to return data as html 
https://{site}.sharepoint.com/{page}/_api/web/lists('{list_id}')/views('{view_id}')/renderashtml
```

Research:  I have taken a look at the rest documentation for sharepoint and I am under the impression you cannot return data from a view. The solution I saw was to first hit the view and then generate a list of columns and use that to build a query to search the list. I have tied that and those fields are not available when I pull the list but are in the view.

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/a5815727-925b-4ac5-8a46-b0979a910ebb/query-listitems-by-view-through-rest-api
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_View

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to get the data from known fields, or discover the names of the fields?

Can you get the desired data by listing the fields in a select?

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=Title,Created,DateOfBirth
```

or to get all of the fields:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=*
```

Comment: I have tried to hit the list by itself, but it has less data on it that what is represented in the view. So even if I try to append a select statement it will fail due to data not being available. The goal I need to solve is returning a query from the view. I have been able to obtain the data using renderashtml, but I feel as though there has to be a better way

Comment: What kind of column is missing? Calculated?

Comment: No, the only info I am pulling is the detailed information (survey data). I need the general info that is who survey it is.

Comment: I was able to pull I'd values of what I was looking for. I should be able to pull that data in as well.

Comment: is it possible to get all the column names for a list?

Comment: Yes, use _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/Fields  See here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133245/get-columns-via-rest